# How do I know what class called the abstract method?

Tags: java, reflection, abstract-class, abstract

say there are 2 classes...

```
public class NotAbstract1 extends AnAbstract {
  NotAbstract1() { super(); }
}

public class NotAbstract2 extends AnAbstract {
  NotAbstract2() { super(); }
}

public abstract class AnAbstract {
  AnAbstract() { //do something }
  abstract void saySomething() { System.out.println("Something"); }
}
```

In this example, `NotAbstract1` and `NotAbstract2` can call `saySomething()`. How can I, from within the `saySomething()` method of `AnAbstract`, recognize the class which called it? **Without passing in the class or an identifier**.

Again, the easy solution is to change the method signature to be `saySomething(Class clazz)` but I'd like to *not* do that. I have a feeling it can be done with reflection so I'm adding that tag to the question.

Comment: Your question may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? How are you going to use knowledge about type of `this` instance? If you have some scenario like `if (this is NotAbstract1){fooX();} else if (this is NotAbstract2){fooY();}` then you should simply add another method to `AnAbstract` like `foo()` and override it in each non-abstract classes and move each `fooX` and `fooY` to this method. This way in `saySomething` you will simply need to call `foo()`.

Comment: Are you asking about the type of `this`? I'm not sure you are.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `this.getClass()` at `saySomething()` - it will return you the type of the current instance - either `notAbstract1` or `notAbstract2`.

Comment: What happens when you have two levels of subclasses, each calling the `super` implementation of `saySomething`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, `getClass()` always returns current instance's type, it is neither affected by your class hierarchy, nor by the method in which it was called.

Comment: You misunderstand me. Take a class `A` which extends class `B` which extends class `AnAbstract`. Both `A` and `B` override the method in question by calling their `super` implementation. If you have an instance of `A` that does this, it will call `B`'s implementation which will call `AnAbstract`'s implementation. `getClass` will return `A`, but from OP's wording of the question, they want `B`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this line will not compile:

```
abstract void saySomething() { System.out.println("Something"); }
```

You cannot both use `abstract` modifier and provide a method body.

For printing the caller's class, you can write:

```
void saySomething() {
    System.out.println(this.getClass().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The abstract keyword in

```
abstract void saySomething();
```

is a place holder.  There cannot be code associated with it.  What it does is ensure that

```
public class NotAbstract1
public class NotAbstract2
```

both have a real implementations like so

```
public class NotAbstract1 extends AnAbstract {
   void saySomething() {
     System.out.println("I'm NotAbstract1");
   }
}

public class NotAbstract2 extends AnAbstract {
   void saySomething() {
     System.out.println("I'm NotAbstract2");
   }
}
```

The compiler does these verifications that the `saySomething()` method exists in the sub classes when you compile `NotAbstract1` and `NotAbstract2`.

When you are holding a

```
AnAbstract object = .... get it from somewhere ...
```

You will be holding either a `NotAbstract1` a `NotAbstract2` or some other subclass of `AnAbstract`, but you will be holding as an`AnAbstract` type.

When you call

```
AnAbstract object = .... get it from somewhere ...
object.saySomething();
```

If the object was originally constructed as a `NotAbstract1` you would run

```
System.out.println("I'm NotAbstract1");
```

If the object was originally constructed as a `NotAbstract2` you would run

```
System.out.println("I'm NotAbstract2");
```

If the object was some other kind of `AnAbstract` you would run whatever was in that sub-class's definition of `saySomething()`.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can check using this.getClass() inside saySomething(), but if you want to have different behaviour of this method based upon which class it is called from you should be ideally overriding saySomething() method in those classes.